# Autofac MultiTenant - how do I route to a subdomain?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

n00b here. Re-asking question because I didn't tag it right.

I am trying to utilize Autofac's MutliTenant feature. I got an example "working" from the source files. I've scanned the docs and am having trouble figuring out how to "route" the tenants.

Currently, I'd like to utilize a single code base for a basic CRUD app. The CRUD app will be used by several different sites, just focused on specific services for the individual site.

I'm wanting to do this eventually:

- codebase.website1.com (Tenant 1)
- codebase.website2.com (Tenant 2)
- codebase.website3.com (Tenant 3)

Any thoughts or references? Thanks.

Comment: Will this underlying CRUD app be a single running instance that is called from within the code for the different sites?  If so, what will be its architecture?

Comment: @MarcL. I was thinking IIS 7.0, Win 2008 R2. Yes, single instance that would be called by website 1 or 2 or 3. So on website 1, there would be a link to codebase.website1.com, etc.  Each user would be authenticated, however, based on the site, so that user 2 from website 2 cannot log on to codebase.website1.com. I hope that makes some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out [the Autofac multitenant documentation on the wiki](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MultitenantIntegration) you'll notice that the way you determine the tenant is by implementing an `ITenantIdentificationStrategy`. There is a sample given on that wiki page showing how to get the tenant from a parameter in the request, like a query string.

It is easy enough to modify the example to look at some other part of the request - the host name, the domain name, or whatever else.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using AutofacContrib.Multitenant;

namespace DemoNamespace
{
  public class DomainStrategy : ITenantIdentificationStrategy
  {
    public bool TryIdentifyTenant(out object tenantId)
    {
      tenantId = null;
      try
      {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if(context != null && context.Request != null)
        {
          var site = context.Request.Url.Authority;
          // Here's where you map the site to the tenant ID:
          tenantId = MapTheSiteToTheTenantId(site);
        }
      }
      catch(HttpException)
      {
        // Happens at app startup in IIS 7.0
      }
      return tenantId != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously you'll need to massage that to work for you. How you do the mapping, whether you return null as the default tenant ID or not, etc.

Note that if you're testing based on an HTTP request value, then any time a dependency is resolved and there is no web context, you're going to get application-level dependencies, not tenant-specific dependencies... because you won't be able to identify the tenant. You see a small artifact of that in the catch block - if any dependencies get resolved at application startup, there's not necessarily a web context so IIS 7.0 throws an HttpException when you call HttpContext.Current. You'll have to test for stuff like that.

Also, you'll want to consider a caching strategy for tenant ID mappings if it's, say, a service call or something expensive. Every time you resolve a multitenant dependency the strategy gets invoked, so you want to make the strategy implementation as efficient as possible.

[I would really recommend checking out that documentation.](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MultitenantIntegration) It's long, but that's because multitenancy is a complex topic and there's a lot of ground to cover. If you dive in there, you'll find the answers to questions like this.

Comment: It was specifically that code that I was looking at and where I was wondering how to implement the strategy (the wiki specifically stated "EXAMPLE ONLY and is NOT RECOMMENDED). Although I see you added code in the `if` block. I am a n00b at this. Do you recommend such a strategy based on domain name as something sound? Appreciate your insights.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to get it now. :)

Comment: The bit that wasn't recommended was using a querystring parameter to switch tenants. Doing that would allow someone to just change their querystring and "be" a different tenant. Using host/domain name is different because you can't really mess around with that and stay on the same "site" - as far as the browser is concerned, you're actually going somewhere else.

Comment: Point is, think carefully about what you choose to be your tenant ID mechanism. Can someone use it as an attack vector? They can't do much with hostname, but querystring I could, say, have a form inject different validation dependencies (on the same site) based on a simple querystring change.

Comment: Those are very good points, thanks. I am just trying to figure out how to do host/domain (again, n00b here). My problem is I am overthinking everything because of the amount of information I am taking in on different forms of doing just what autofac does.

Comment: Just curious, how we will handle incorrect subdomains. Say like user entered blah.website.com. Then we should redirect that user to an error page. How we could do that ?